# Calling function in API retrieves Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Tags: sql-server, api, model-view-controller, procedure

I'm working on a code with a stored procedure in mvc framework. I have a field WorkOverDate to pick a date and save it in Unit table. After it is saved I'm looking to add that date into another table called WorkOver. 
The problem comes when I try to call the function with the stored procedure in the api that updated the info in the Unit and I get this:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
I'm not sure what to do here. Everything I modify in the page, saves correctly, but the stored procedure doesn't work. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

I have a UnitRepository file which has the following code:

```
public void UpdateWorkOver()
        {

            using (var cmd = _db.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {

                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.WorkOverAddDate";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                bool isOpen = cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open;
                if (!isOpen)
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                }

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                if (!isOpen)
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                }
            }

        }
```

The stored procedure for this is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[WorkOverAddDate]

AS

INSERT INTO dbo.WorkOver 
           (UnitID, WODate, CreatedBy, Created) 

SELECT UnitID, WODate, CreatedBy, Created

FROM dbo.WorkOver

UNION

SELECT  ID, WorkOverDate, UpdatedBy, Updated

FROM dbo.Unit
```

Also, I have an API where I'm calling the function with the Stored Procedure when saving the page.

//Edit

```
                    unit.Updated = DateTime.Now;
                    unit.UpdatedBy = _securityHelper.CurrentUserID.ToString();
                    _auditHelper.After = unit;

                    _repoUnit.Edit(unit);
                    if (unit.WorkOverDate != null)
                    { ((UnitRepository)_repoUnit).UpdateWorkOver(); }
```

Comment: it's look like a little bit strange: ```if (!isOpen) cmd.Connection.Close();```.

Comment: Add try...catch exception handling to your code and log SqlException details, or step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: The posted stored procedure code appears to be duplicating all of the existing rows in dbo.WorkOrder and adding new row(s) from dbo.Unit. If you execute the stored procedure in SSMS do you get some kind of unique constraint violation?

Comment: So in the web console, I get this: jquery.js:9172 POST https://localhost:44301/api/unit 500 and in the debug I get Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.SqlClient.dll

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, you are right, I just tried it now. I thought that union was returning distinct values only?

Comment: The problem was that I had to add in the stored procedure : Where WorkOverDate IS NOT NULL   Now it's working. But how can I make it do not duplicate the existing rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had to add in the stored procedure :

```
Where WorkOverDate IS NOT NULL
```

as a null parameter cannot be added to a column that is not nullable. Now it's working.